# Invisible Material?

Tags: materials

All of my materials just became like this in Material & Rendered Preview. This affects all of my .blend file, even the newly created ones. [image]

Texture in Solid Preview is still normal though.[image]

I don't know how did I created this mess. Any suggestion ?